# How to format a number with specific number of digits?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I need to show a list like: 1,2,3,etc but show it like: 0001,0001,0003, etc

Exists a template filter in Django to to that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplifying karthikr's answer, you can leverage one of the already provided django template tags to accomplish this:

```
{{ number|stringformat:"04d" }}
```

Comment: Since the answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation